# How long is it ok to keep a connection to a MySql db open?

Tags: python, mysql, database

I have a python which has to work 24/7 on a server. It constantly receives data and it inserts it into a MySql db. The 
frequency can vary, and in general it's approximately:

```
1 write / 1 second minimun and 

1 write / 30 minutes maximum.
```

There're other clients who can read from the same db and tables but those are separate applications.

Given this, should I ever close a connection from my python script to the MySql db? Maybe I should have a timer, so I have no data to insert within 10 minutes, I should close the connection? And then open it again when data comes.

Comment: I guess a good question would be how fast does the script need to go from receiving the data to inputting it into the database? Theoretically you should be able to actually keep the connection alive for weeks or even months without issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As:

- the connexion is unique (it is one, clearly identified for one application, not 'x' connexions depending on the charge, the number of visitors, users etc...),
- closing/reopening connexions is a process which consumes probably more resources than keeping it in a 'sleeping' state
- there is no absolute need to have a minimum amount of exchange between the server, once you have properly configured the 'wait_timeout' variable on the MySQL server (cf. [MySQL doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout)): its default value is 8 hours ; its maximum value is ... one year.

Concrete example: I have myself a 'frontend server' which is running on a first dedicated server ; this server is quite light and relies on another (physical) bigger, stronger server which holds the (big) MySQL database.
The 'frontend server' connects to the remote database once during its boot (via SSH tunneling & port forwarding, on linux) ; and the connexion is then kept for months.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a good practice to always close connections.

If you don't close connections, other clients could run into the issue "Too many connections", depending on how many connection your MySQL server can handle.